# How to get a single document in firestore and display it on a site

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I cant't find a way to get a single document from Cloud Firestore on a website. Let's say I have this Collection on my Cloud Firestore (Not realtime DB):

```
StoreSales:
 StoreA
    Jan:1
    Feb:5
    Mar:10
    Apr:2
    May:3 
 StoreB 
    Jan:1
    Feb:5
    Mar:5
    Apr:6
    May:3
 StoreC
    Jan:1
    Feb:5
    Mar:2
    Apr:2
    May:1
```

And I have this code to retrieve some data:

```
const Stores = document.querySelector('#sales-list');

function renderSales(doc){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let sales = document.createElement('span');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    sales.textContent = doc.data().StoreSales;

    li.appendChild(sales);

    Stores.appendChild(li);
}

db.collection('StoreSales').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        renderSales(doc);
    });
});
```

And what that ends up doing is getting all data, no matter the document and no matter what's inside the sub collections, it will get for example what's on Store A, B and C, and their contents.

I wanted to target and display specific data, like for example show the StoreB April sales.
What can I modify to get this result?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the **exact** non-working code, along with a description of what it does that's not the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson , just edited it to make it less confusing, and straight to what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a single document when you know its ID is a straightforward case covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).  I suggest reviewing it.  You can use `doc()` to create a reference to that document.

```
db.collection('StoreSales').doc('StoreA').get().then(snapshot => {
    // Do what you want with the DocumentSnapshot here
});
```

Comment: It only worked for me as db.collection('StoreSales').doc('StoreA').get().then(function(doc) {
   console.log('Document: ', ' => ', doc.data());
    });  , but it's still getting all the months from the cloud. doc.getDouble('Jan') for example does not work. I read that documentation some times, but I found it to be very confusing.

Comment: If your months are individual fields in a document, then they will always all become part of the document snapshot in a query.  There are no partial document queries that get only certain fields.

Comment: Snapshot was not working here when I ran btw, don't know why. But on android I can for example call val number= document.getDouble("Jan") after calling the referenced document, and while it may download all the fields, it will let me manipulate only the ones I want (a double in this case), and display it, math it with something else, etc. Is this not possible on javascript?

Comment: Each client platoform API works the same. You should look at the API documentation for DocumentSnapshot to understand its specific API.  Use get(). https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot

Comment: Thanks, that worked very well. I could for example do document.getElementById("StoreA").textContent= doc.get('jan'); and have it's value displayed on page.